# Programmatically / dynamically adjust SSH session port forwards

Tags: shell-script, ssh, ssh-tunneling, openssh

I have a workflow where I am trying to do the following:

For a given existing SSH session, access the remote machine and perform a process from which a port is returned (e.g. a remote daemon has been started). Using this port, I would like to create a new port forward from within the existing session by using the `EscapeChar` technique to instantiate an SSH shell within the session and construct the new port forward.

My question is the following:

How do I -- from a shell script or equivalent -- programmatically perform SSH session modifications wherein the EscapeChar is required?

Comment: For clarification, you basically want to send the EscapeChar within that session to show forwarded connections ( ~# by default ) and then parse that output, and add/delete/change forwardings based upon that?

Seems you'd need something like expect for that. See [this](http://blog.wains.be/2010/04/29/ssh-add-port-forwardings-on-a-live-connection-with-escapechar/) or [that](https://coderwall.com/p/5wp2wg/start-port-forwarding-over-an-existing-ssh-connection-instead-of-creating-a-new-one) link for basic usage, and [this link for expect help](http://expect.sourceforge.net/]

Answer (score 0):

Not what you asked for, but have you seen the "-D" option, to turn ssh into a SOCKS5 server?  Then you can just run programs on the local side behind `tsocks` and connect to anything you like on the remote end.