# Add Forward during SSH Session (Dynamically)

Tags: ssh, port-forwarding

We know that we can specify Local or Dynamic Port Forwarding through `ssh` by specifying command-line parameters:

```
ssh -D #### \         # For Dynamic Forwards
    -L ####:host:#### # For Local Forwards
```

But if I forget to specify a forward, can I somehow add one during the session, without having to close the connection and start a new session?

PuTTY (on Windows) can do this, but `ssh` is a different application.

Answer (score 2):

As I discovered in [a comment on a similar question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/170270/13308#comment281010_170270), `ssh` supports the EscapeChar, which is the tilde (`~`) character by default. With this EscapeChar, you can perform many tasks, including the modification of Port Forwarding. The EscapeChar only works following a new line, so you may need to insert a newline (i.e. by pressing `enter`).

Assuming that `~` is the EscapeChar, `~?` will list the available options. The SSH command line provides the interface to add a new port forwarding route, with `~C`. To add a Local or Dynamic Forward, use:

```
~C
ssh> -L ####:host:####
Forwarding port.
~C
ssh> -D ####
Forwarding port.
# Even without a prompt, your input has returned to the remote session
```

Comment: Is there a way to script this? I tried:

    # echo '
    > ~C -L 8443:localhost:8443
    > ' > /dev/tty

but only got me that on stdout.

Comment: You can't script it on the server side, since it is a client-side input to the `ssh` client. You can add it to your client-side `~/.ssh/config` file under a `Host` section as `LocalForward #port# host:#port#` or `DynamicForward #port#`.

Comment: I never said server side, but it doesn't seem to be scriptable in the client side either. I can input all that in the session's console, but I can't put a line in a `bash` script to it.